# How do I resolve ffmpeg concat command error "unknown keyword..."?

Tags: shell, command-line, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two video files using ffmpeg, and I am receiving an error.

To eliminate compatibility issues between the two videos, I have been concatenating the same video with itself, and the same error persists.

```
ffmpeg \
  -f concat \
  -safe 0 \
  -i intro_prepped.avi intro_prepped.avi \
  -c copy \
  concat.avi
```

And the error output I receive is....

> [concat @ 0x220d420] Line 1: unknown keyword 'RIFFf�?'
> intro_prepped.avi: Invalid data found when processing input

I have tried various combinations of concat flags and have not been able to get it to work. Has anyone seen this error before?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Docs for several ways of concatenating files: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Here's a command I use to concatenate videos:

```
ffmpeg \
  -i "concat:input1.avi|input2.avi|input3.avi" \
  -c:a copy \
  -c:v copy \
  output.avi
```

Comment: I tried:

`    ffmpeg -i "concat:media3.mp4|media4.mp4|media5.mp4" -c:a copy -c:v copy output.mp4`

And it just produced a copy of media3.mp4, without any concatenation. However, this version from your link worked:

`    ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4`

worked, where `mylist.txt` was:

`    # this is a comment
    file 'media3.mp4'
    file 'media4.mp4'
    file 'media5.mp4'`

Any idea what the difference is here?

Comment: the difference is the word **file**. Look at my answer below

Comment: This file-level copy method only work for some formats (MPEG-1, MPEG-2 PS, DV) , but not for mp4.

Answer (score 20):

This is a bit late for the original post, but I was just searching for answers to the same problem so I think it's still relevant and I haven't found any more recent posts answering the same problem.

I found that my **.txt** file was encoded wrong. I opened the file in Notepad and did a 'Save As...'
I changed the encoding to **UTF-8** and the **ffmpeg concat** command worked.

Comment: This was the issue for me too. Thank you. 
For those using Notepad++, the same can be done there with the 'Encoding' tab on the main title bar.

Comment: Click on current encoding name on right side of status bar or press Ctrl+Shift+P - and type "Change File Encoding" to achieve this in VSCode.

Answer (score 11):

I tried all of the aforementioned and it didn't work.

It looks like that the file names in the list have to be specially formatted to look like:

**file '/path/to/file1.wav'**

with a word **file** included. I spend a lot of time trying to guess why ffmpeg encountered an error trying to read the file names. It didn't matter if they were in the list or in the command line. So only after I utilized a command

```
for f in *.wav; do echo "file '$f'" >> mylist.txt; done
```

to make list from ffmpeg's manual I had success. The only difference was an additional word **file**.

Here you can read it yourself: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer

Answer (score 6):

Your text file is likely encoded in UTF-16.

**Fix:** (Windows 10)

- Open text file
- Select 'Save as'
- Look by the save button, you get to pick encoding with a drop down box, select UTF-8.
- Save and run ffmpeg again.

I used the Powershell code on ffmpegs webpage to make a text file with filenames, and Powershell seems to save text files as some variant of UTF-16, so I chose the safer UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

The input file should be a text file, not an avi. The text file lists the files to concatenate.

See the [concat demuxer documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) and [FFmpeg Wiki: Concat](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Comment: Is there a way to concatenate two files on the command line? I am doing it from a bash script and do not know the file names ahead of time.

Comment: Sure. See the other examples in that link.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody had a full, working, concat text file batch file anywhere. So I am posting it

```
md ts
for %%x in (input\*.m4a) do (ffmpeg -i "%%x" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb ts\%%~nx.ts)
for %%c in ("ts\*ts") do (echo file '%%c')>>list.txt
for %%f in (input\*.m4a) do (set fn=%%~nf)
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "list.txt" -c copy "%cd%\%fn%".m4a
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with all these instructions above on my Mac (M1, Ventura, ffmpeg version N-109530-g4a80db5fc2-tessus). None of them worked for me - but a combination of all did the trick!

This is how I got it running:

- place all input files the same folder
- create `input.txt` in this folder - content looks like this:

  ```
  file 'input1.mp4'
  file 'input2.mp4'
  file 'input3.mp4'
  file 'input4.mp4'
  ```

  - **Note:**

    - file encoding must be `UTF-8`
    - `file` keyword must be present
    - filename must not be fully qualified (I got exceptions using `'/path/to/input1.mp4'`)
    - filename must be enclosed by `'`
- navigate to this folder in the terminal
- execute `ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy ffmpegOUT.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

Latest:

Using windows 10

1. gather files using this with sort according to date modification:

   ```
   foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.mp4 | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime) {echo "file '$i'" >> mylist.txt}
   ```
2. save as the mylist as UTF-8
3. combine them by running this at powershell:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -vcodec copy output.mp4
   ```
4. ffmpeg must be installed to use directly.
5. if you want to just directly use ffmpeg exe without installation then use:

   ```
    ./ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -vcodec copy output.mp4
   ```

   given that ffmpeg.exe is in the same directory and powershell is at that directrory

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked by disabling BOM on the UTF-8 format. So the file was UTF-8 and noBOM.

e.g. the contents of the text file:

```
file 'video1.mp4'
file 'video2.mp4'
file 'video3.mp4'
```

and use:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input_videos.txt -c copy ffmpeg_out.mp4
```